# Lista/menu corta los campos o excede del ancho de pantalla

Tags: css, lista

conocen algún sistema para que una lista/menu con algunos campos muy largos y otros cortos no utilice mas del 100% de la pantalla y no corte el texto?
Los campos se leen desde una base de datos. Muchas gracias
[CAPTURA PANTALLA 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua8bY.png)

[image: CAPTURA DE PANTALLA 2]

Hola he probrado lasolución propuesta y el resultado no es el esperado,Disculpen, pongo el código modificado y la nueva captura:

```css
.caja-padre{
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
background-color: #ff4000;
}
.padre-texto{
width: 95%; /* Puedes cambiar que tanto ocupe el cuadro */
margin: auto; /* Se centra para que tenga su función */
}
```

```html
<select name="borrar" class="caja-padre">
 <%
While (NOT datos_SCIM_ALI.EOF)
%>
  <option class="padre-texto" value="<%=(datos_SCIM_ALI.Fields.Item("DATO").Value)%>"><%=(datos_SCIM_ALI.Fields.Item("DATO").Value)%></option>
  <%
  datos_SCIM_ALI.MoveNext()
Wend
If (datos_SCIM_ALI.CursorType > 0) Then
  datos_SCIM_ALI.MoveFirst
Else
  datos_SCIM_ALI.Requery
End If
%></select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, por favor, añade el código HTML y CSS que hayas intentado para poder ver el problema directamente en la pregunta. Así será más fácil ayudarte. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve], y completa el [tour] para más información.

Comment: Añadido, disculpar el error

Answer (score 0):

Según creo, la caja padre tiene un ancho definido y la caja hijo tiene otro ancho, y al hacer esto se desbordará....

Tienes que especificar cúal será el ancho máximo y sólo aplicarselo a la caja padre. te dejaré un ejemplo:

```css
.ejemplo-caja-padre-1{
width: 90%; /* Se le dice que la caja padre solo ocupe el  90% del ancho de la página, se usa % para que la caja se vaya adaptando en ancho a las diferentes resoluciones, tablet, movil etc... */
margin: 0 auto; /* Esto centrará la caja para que no quede a la izquierda */
height: 200px; /* El alto de la caja padre siempre deber ser en px, cuando es una caja hijo, entonces se usa % */
background-color: #000;
}
.caja-hijo-1{
height: 50%; /* Al ser una caja hijo y su padre tiene una altura definidad en px, entonces manejo su altura en %, en este caso le digo que ocupe la mitad de la caja padre */
background-color: #ff0;
/* No hace falta definirle el ancho a la caja hijo, ella misma se adaptará */
}
.texto-caja-hijo-1{
padding: 10px; /* En este caso, le doy un padding al texto, esto hace que el texto no quede pegado a la caja hijo. le da relleno dejando el texto con espacio tanto arriba, abajo y a los lados. es lo que andas buscando */
}
.ejemplo-caja-padre-2{
width: 100%; /* En este caso la caja padre 2 ocupará el 100% de la pantalla en ancho */
background-color: #000080;
}
.texto-caja-padre-2{
/* Puedes hacer lo mismo que padding, pero esta es otra manera. lo que hace este ejemplo es que el texto ocupe solo el 90% de ancho de su caja padre */
width: 90%;
margin: auto; 
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- EJEMPLO 1 -->
<div class="ejemplo-caja-padre-1">
<!-- BASANDOME EN LO QUE CREO QUE TIENES, INCLUYO UNA CAJA HIJO -->
<div CLASS="caja-hijo-1">

<p class="texto-caja-hijo-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et accumsan elit. Nam rutrum aliquet nibh, sed venenatis enim fermentum sed. Suspendisse pretium tortor vel orci tempus, et ultrices nulla ornare</p>

</div>

</div>



<br>


<!-- EJEMPLO 2 -->
<div class="ejemplo-caja-padre-2">
<!-- NO INCLUYO UNA CAJA HIJO, SUPONIENDO QUE LO TIENES ASÍ -->
<p class="texto-caja-padre-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et accumsan elit. Nam rutrum aliquet nibh, sed venenatis enim fermentum sed. Suspendisse pretium tortor vel orci tempus, et ultrices nulla ornare</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Hola Codeadicto, he probado la solución y no consigo el resultado esperado, arriba lo muestro.Muchas gracias

Comment: Se desborda la caja o tiene ese ancho?

Comment: La caja se desborda por qué algunos de los campos son extremadamente largo hasta 3 líneas en Word

Comment: Ocupa más del 100% del ancho del navegador y aparece un scroll horizontal

Comment: Ya he actualizado la respuesta, espero que sea lo que buscas, si no es así, publica todo tu codigo para ver que es lo que haces mal, saludos.